# Почему сторонние библиотеки подключаются в #include через <>, а не "" ? C++

Tags: c++, include, library

Заметил, что в библиотеках, написанными пользователями, зачастую подключают свои же заголовочные файлы не через " #include "file.h" ", а " #include <Directory/file.h> ". Но разве <> - это не для системных библиотек? Зачем это делаeтся и как это сделать со своим проектом?

Comment: `< >` указывает лишь на то что файл находится в указанной системной папке, или папках ( например в linux по пути `/usr/include/`) в кавычках же указываются те файлы которые расположены локально в папке с проектом, со своим проектом в процессе разработки вполне хватит `" "`

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/include

Comment: @DaniilLoban, не совсем так. В кавычках задают поиск заголовочных файлов сначала в текущем каталоге, а потом в системных. Угловые скобки - поиск заголовочных файлов идет только по системным каталогам, как Вы и указали.

Comment: @Fat-Zer, ну, вот Вам из документации: Searches for the file in implementation-defined manner. The intent of this syntax is to search for the files under control of the implementation. Typical implementations search **only** standard include directories. The standard C++ library and the standard C library are implicitly included in these standard include directories. The standard include directories usually can be controlled by the user through compiler options. Написано, что обычно, да, а не всегда. Например, это могли в MSVC сделать иначе, т.к. у них свой лунапарк.

Comment: @Vladimir, да, я уже понял, что был не прав...